# Beautifulsoup: Loop through class and extract information

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://www.amcham.com.au/web/Events/Web/Events/Upcoming_Events.aspx?hkey=6f098583-ca3d-4a6f-87de-cd4f13d50b11')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

event_title = soup.find('span', {'class': 'eventTitle'})
event_location = soup.find('span', {'class': 'city'})
event_place =  soup.find('span', {'class': 'place'})
event_date =  soup.find('span', {'class': 'eventDate'})


print(event_title.text)
print(event_place.text,event_location.text)
print(event_date.text)
```

I'm using this code to extract upcoming events Titles,location,date information from the website.

I'm looking forward to loop throught the entire series on events in the website and extract event title,location,place,date information, Can some one help me with the same?

Comment: `soup.find()` only returns the first matching item.  You probably want to use `soup.find_all()` to return all the items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `findAll` to get a full listing for each:

```
event_title = [i.text for i in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'eventTitle'})]
event_location = [i.text for i in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'city'})]
event_place = [i.text for i in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'place'})]
event_date =  [i.text for i in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'eventDate'})]
```

Comment: Thanks, Now able to print the all the required infromation

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach can be something like below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://www.amcham.com.au/web/Events/Web/Events/Upcoming_Events.aspx?hkey=6f098583-ca3d-4a6f-87de-cd4f13d50b11')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

for item in soup.find_all(class_=["rgRow","rgAltRow"]):
    event_title = item.find(class_='eventTitle').text
    event_location = item.find(class_='city').text
    event_place =  item.find(class_='place').text
    event_date =  item.find(class_='eventDate').text
    print(event_title,event_location,event_place,event_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Optimized solution with single `select` query:

```
import requests, pprint
import collections
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://www.amcham.com.au/web/Events/Web/Events/Upcoming_Events.aspx?hkey=6f098583-ca3d-4a6f-87de-cd4f13d50b11')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

event_data = collections.defaultdict(list)
for el in soup.select('span.eventTitle, span.city, span.place, span.eventDate'):
    event_data[el['class'][0]].append(el.text)

pprint.pprint(dict(event_data))
```

*Pretty* output:

```
{'city': ['The Rocks, NSW',
          'Brisbane, QLD',
          'Sydney, NSW',
          'Richmond, VIC',
          'Adelaide, SA',
          'Perth, WA',
          'Melbourne, VIC',
          'Pyrmont, NSW',
          'South Wharf, VIC'],
 'eventDate': ['Mon22Jan',
               'Mon5Feb',
               'Fri9Feb',
               'Tue20Feb',
               'Fri23Feb',
               'Thu8Mar',
               'Wed14Mar',
               'Thu15Mar',
               'Mon19Mar',
               'Tue20Mar',
               'Wed21Mar',
               'Fri23Mar',
               'Wed30May'],
 'eventTitle': ['AMCHAM & UNITED AIRLINES PRESENT',
                'Super Bowl LII',
                'AMCHAM SUPER BOWL LII - SYDNEY',
                'SUPER BOWL LII NETWORKING EVENT',
                'MR SANJEEV GUPTA',
                'Meet the Minister Luncheon with The Hon. Alannah MacTiernan',
                'ADVANCING WOMEN IN LEADERSHIP',
                'GLOBAL CITIZENS: DRIVING THE FUTURE OF EXPERIENCE',
                "INTERNATIONAL WOMEN'S DAY",
                'THE EXECUTIVE SPIN ON SERVICE',
                'TOLL GROUP',
                'THE SCIENCE BEHIND LEADERSHIP',
                'PEAK PERFORMANCE LEADERSHIP SUMMIT',
                'WORLD BUSINESS FORUM: TWO-DAY EVENT'],
 'place': ['Shangri-La Hotel',
           'The Pav Bar',
           'Hotel CBD',
           'Richmond Football Club',
           'InterContinental',
           'CBD Venue',
           'Karstens',
           'Sydney CBD',
           'Plaza Ballroom',
           'RACV Club',
           'The Star',
           'Melbourne Convention Centre']}
```